# Understanding Yann Martel's description of a tree

Tags: yann-martel, beatrice-and-virgil

In an article titled "[Why Yann Martel’s Beatrice and Virgil is the Worst Book of the Decade](http://www.edrants.com/why-yann-martels-beatrice-and-virgil-is-the-worst-book-of-the-decade/)", a reviewer complains about the following passage in *Beatrice and Virgil* (located on pages 18-19):

> He was near a tree, the soil around it soft and bare, and the impact of his foot-stamping was thunderous, certainly to him, and a couple lying nearby turned his way because of it. Henry stood, amazed. The ground had trembled. He had felt the reverberation. The earth itself had heard him, he thought. He looked up at the tree. It was a giant tree, a galleon with its sails in full rig, an art museum with its entire collection on display, a mosque with a thousand worshippers praising God. He gazed at it for several minutes. A tree had never before been so soothing to him. As he admired it, he could feel the anger and distress draining from him.

The review describes this passage as overwrought and unnecessary. Specifically, the reviewer seems to feel that this passage could be replaced with a single sentence about Henry stamping his foot, and that the description of the reverberation and the tree is repetitive.

Does this passage serve a purpose that the reviewer is overlooking?

Comment: Hard to tell out of context. Is it a "magical realism" book?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum "Hard to tell out of context": exactly, answering this question requires reading the book at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. Critical responses to *Beatrice and Virgil* have a tendency to completely miss the point of what is a sophisticated and innovative book. I suppose it's understandable when it's just [one blog post](http://www.edrants.com/why-yann-martels-beatrice-and-virgil-is-the-worst-book-of-the-decade/), but when [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/13/books/13book.html) and [The Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2010/04/13/AR2010041303903.html) do the same thing... I suppose it's fine if you personally didn't enjoy *Beatrice and Virgil*, but criticizing the writing style when the writing style supports themes that you didn't take the time to understand? That's something else entirely.

*Beatrice and Virgil* is a novel about how to talk about events when language isn't working. We're first introduced to this theme through Martel's analysis of the Holocaust on page 20:

> His flip book was about having his soul ripped out and with it, attached, his tongue. Wasn’t that what every Holocaust book was about, aphasia? Henry remembered a statistic: fewer than two percent of Holocaust survivors ever write about or testify to their ordeal. Thus the typical approach of those who do speak about it, so precise and factual, like a stroke victim who’s learning how to speak again and who starts with the simplest, clearest syllables.

Critics have argued that it's arrogant for the Henry to compare his book to the experiences of Holocaust survivors. But if you consider the fact that Henry represents Yann Martel the author, and that the flip book represents the book *Beatrice and Virgil*, you'll see that Martel is just introducing his book to his readers. What is *Beatrice and Virgil* about? It's about being unable to talk about a traumatic event, but finding ways to talk about it anyway.

Now let's turn to the so-called "overwritten" passage about the tree:

> He was near a tree, the soil around it soft and bare, and the impact of his foot-stamping was thunderous, certainly to him, and a couple lying nearby turned his way because of it. Henry stood, amazed. The ground had trembled. He had felt the reverberation. The earth itself had heard him, he thought. He looked up at the tree. It was a giant tree, a galleon with its sails in full rig, an art museum with its entire collection on display, a mosque with a thousand worshippers praising God. He gazed at it for several minutes. A tree had never before been so soothing to him. As he admired it, he could feel the anger and distress draining from him.

Trees can't talk. Trees can't use language. But in this passage, we see that the tree is able to respond to Henry's actions, and that Henry and the tree are able to communicate ("the earth had heard him, he thought").

One of the reasons why people hate *Beatrice and Virgil* is because it compares the Holocaust to the treatment of animals at the hands of humans. ([It's a comparison made by many Holocaust survivors](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/michael-a-webermann/why-is-a-holocaust-surviv_b_5882926.html), by the way). In Martel's "overwritten" passage about the tree, Martel introduces a new, unique point of comparison between Holocaust survivors and animals: they have trouble talking about their traumatic experiences! But at the same time, Martel's description of the tree is a message of hope: through some process that we don't understand yet, the tree is able to respond and communicate. How that communication can happen is explored in rest of the book.

Martel's *Beatrice and Virgil* is a tour de force examination of language, metaphor, communication, and how literature can shed light on the unexplainable. It's a pity that none of the reviewers were able to pick up on that.